# How to delete all woocommerce messages (added to cart, removed from cart etc.)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to find a simple workaround to hide all woocommerce messages on my website, e.g. product was added to the cart, product was removed from the cart etc.

I have found some workaround for individual messages (such as the ones listed above) by adding specific lines to functions.php, but am trying to find a code that would turn ALL woocommerce messages off.

I will greatly appreciate your help.

Thanks,

Kacper

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tested but

```
<!-- Hide all WooCommerce notices -->
.woocommerce-notices-wrapper {
     display: none;
}
```

should do the trick.

Just place it in your child theme's style.css

Comment: Abhishek - appreciate it. It works great! Do you have any suggestions as to how I could solve the messages on checkout ('X is required field'). The code you have provided does not influence these and I am also looking for a way to hide them. Thanks!

Comment: try **.woocommerce-NoticeGroup.woocommerce-NoticeGroup-checkout { display: none; }**

Comment: Although, I'm not sure if it's a good idea to hide all these unless you have this stuff handled separately. You could also end up hiding potentially useful messages.

Comment: This did the job as well! What do you mean by 'having this stuff handled separately'?

Comment: What I mean is that those notices are there for a reason. If no info is provided to the customer then they may find themselves confused when an action fails on them. If you are hiding these default messages then you should have a system of your own so that you could convey the same to the customer in an alternative method.